# Format datetime with moment.js to show timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I have problem showing timezone with moment.js.

I tried with this code:

```
var result = moment(someDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A Z");
```

and I get return, for example: `08/05/2015 06:18 PM +02:00`, which is fine, but I want that my output be like `08/05/2015 06:18 PM WEDT` or something like that, with abbreviations of timezones.

Tried using this code, but I get empty timezone on the end:

```
var result = moment(someDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A z");
```

or

```
var result = moment(someDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A zz");
```

UPDATE

So as @Matt Johnson suggested, I used this approach to show time zone using [moment-timezone-with-data.js](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js) and [tzdetect.js](https://github.com/Canop/tzdetect.js):

```
var tzName = tzdetect.matches()[0];
var result = moment.tz(myDate, tzName).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A zz");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As described [in the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

> Note: as of 1.6.0, the z/zz format tokens have been deprecated. [Read more about it here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162).

The general problem is that time zone abbreviations are not available from the browser through a consistent API.  In order to provide them, one has to have an external source of data.

You may want to look into using the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) addon.  It provides time zone information, including abbreviations.  You would have to know the specific time zone you are working with.  For example:

```
moment.tz("2015-08-05T00:00:00+01:00", "Europe/London").format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A z");
// "08/05/2015 12:00 AM BST"
```

Also, you shouldn't mix `HH` (hours of the 24-hour clock) with `A` (the 12-hour am/pm designator).   Either use `hh` with `A`, or use `HH` without `A`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I'm just reading your other answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28377706/1081079 and I think that I can combine this two approaches to get what I need.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that one. :)

Answer (score 3):

To Convert UTC datetime to user's current timezone the solution is to use moment-timezone instead of moment.(We have all dates as UTC in DB). Other timezones shouldn't be an issue either.

```
const timeZoneString = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
const getFormattedDateTimeWithTZ = (date) => {
      return moment((date)).tz(timeZoneString).format('ddd, MMM DD YYYY, h:mm A zz')
}
// outputs Tue, Mar 08 2022, 4:00 PM PKT
getFormattedDateTimeWithTZ('2022-03-08T03:00:00.000-08:00')
```