# How to display timezone using momentjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to display a date like this, with current timezone

**Jul 20, 2017 2:39pm EDT**

What I manage to get is this

```
<Moment format="MMM DD, YYYY h:mma">{new Date()}</Moment>
```

Output: **Jul 20, 2017 2:39pm**

I also found this

```
<Moment>{new Date()}</Moment>
```

Output: **Thu Jul 20 2017 15:16:50 GMT-0400**

But I don't want all the extra stuff, I just to display timezone name.

Comment: But i don't want to specify the zone, i want to display current zone @VipulSingh

Answer (score 0):

The general problem is that time zone abbreviations are not available from the browser through a consistent API. In order to provide them, one has to have an external source of data.

-There is also now built-in support for time zone detection/guessing in [momentjs timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```
var tzName = moment.tz.guess();
var abbr = m.tz(tzName).zoneAbbr();  // or .format('z')
```

More importantly, you can find other options in this post [Get timezone abbreviation using offset value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374901/get-timezone-abbreviation-using-offset-value/28377706#28377706)