# How to get timezone location from time zone in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

How to get timezone location from time zone in angularjs. I have a time zone like this `GMT+5:30` i want the location name `Asia/Kolkata.`

Comment: A timezone offset like +05:30 applies to many different places. You can't determine which one a particular offset applies to any more than you can identify a place only using its longitude (or in the case of timezone, a range of longitudes). E.g. Asia/Calcutta, Asia/Colombo and Asia/Kolkata all use +05:30.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/getting-zone-names/ I couldnt figure out how to get this working but you might find your answer along these lines

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374901/get-timezone-abbreviation-using-offset-value

Comment: @Isaac—that will guess the timezone (and is not reliable), it will not provide a location as requested by the OP.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara—that is not a duplicate (if that's what you're suggesting).

Comment: @RobG I was assuming the OP didnt need it to be that specific (as this is not possible, a lot of cities lie on the same timezones and the OP should know this, also part of the reason I degraded my answer to a comment). It's probably as close as they're going to get though

Comment: @Isaac—yes, it's not possible: "*I want the location name Asia/Kolkata.*" ;-)

Comment: @RobG it is not, but it may help.

Comment: I want exactly what RobG sed @Isaac

Comment: @byteC0de then good luck