# Detect timezone abbreviation using luxon

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, luxon

Moment timezone results with short timezone abbreviations, e.g

```
moment.tz([2012, 0], 'America/New_York').format('z');    // EST
moment.tz([2012, 5], 'America/New_York').format('z');    // EDT
```

Is there a similar way we can achieve that using luxon

I tried `offsetNameShort`, but, it results to `GMT+5:30` for a date like `"2020-05-23T13:30:00+05:30"`

Something like `DateTime.fromISO(""2020-05-23T13:30:00+05:30"").toFormat('z')` doesn't work either

Is there a way we can remove the `+5:30` timezone from the format?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Review [Luxon's table of formatting tokens](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=table-of-tokens).  You want `ZZZZ` for the abbreviated named offset.

Examples:

```
DateTime.fromObject({year: 2012, month: 1, zone: 'America/New_York'})
  .toFormat('ZZZZ') //=> "EST"

DateTime.fromObject({year: 2012, month: 6, zone: 'America/New_York'})
  .toFormat('ZZZZ') //=> "EDT"

DateTime.local()
  .toFormat('ZZZZ') //=> "PDT"  (on my computer)

DateTime.fromISO("2020-05-23T13:30:00+05:30", {zone: 'Asia/Kolkata', locale: 'en-IN'})
  .toFormat('ZZZZ') //=> "IST"
```

Note in that last one, you also have to specify `en-IN` as the locale to get `IST`.  Otherwise you will get `GMT+05:30`, unless the system locale is *already* `en-IN`.  That is because Luxon relies upon the browser's internationalization APIs, which in turn takes its data from [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/).

In CLDR, many names and abbreviations are designated as being specific to a given locale, rather than being used worldwide.  The same thing happens with `Europe/London` getting `GMT+1` instead of `BST` unless the locale is `en-GB`.   (I personally disagree with this, but that is how it is currently implemented.)

Comment: This explains why the DateTImeFormat *timeZoneName: 'short'* option sometimes shows the offset and other times shows the abbreviation. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's a quirk of CLDR data that some names are assigned at the country level rather than the language level.   Not sure why, but so it is.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint `DateTime` has `offsetNameLong` and `offsetNameShort` as instance properties, which are slightly clearer than the format token

Comment: updated Link: https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=table-of-tokens

Answer (score -2):

just simply use

```
const shortDate = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-us',{timeZoneName:'short'});
console.log(shotrDate.split(' ')[2]); // EST
```

Comment: This version has several caveats like not working for AEST: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34405528/1101109