I need to get as "ist" or "est" from a user-based location from JavaScript date
I am using JavaScript date method for date and getting mentioned result.
const d = new Date();

output is:  Tue May 07 2024 14:57:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
But I need this format
IST instead of India Standard Time
Tue May 07 2024 14:57:43 GMT+0530 (IST)

I need "IST" instead of "India Standard Time"

new Date().toString().replace("India Standard Time", "IST")

So, you want to "replace" the string "India Standard Time" with "IST"?

I need for all GMT times. Like "EST" for "Eastern Standard Time" or "PST" for "pacific standard time" or "IST" for "Indian standard time".

This answer looks like it might be hit and miss but would work for your use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63282162/2181514

TBH not sure it will ever 100% work as ITC = Irish Standard Time - along with 6 other timezones that are all "IST"

According to the specification (step #9), the timezone name displayed there is coming from an abstract operation with no further specification and it can also be empty. The value depends on factors like summer/winter-time and even the language (support) from the operating system/browser/environment. It's best to ignore the value displayed in parentheses and use the GMT value provided in the date.toString() function if needed.

@fdomn-m it won't: It fails also on CET / Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit simply returning MS, if the OS language and browser language is set to german.

You can achieve the desired format by using the toLocaleString() method with options to customize the output.
const d = new Date();
const options = { timeZoneName: 'short' };
const formattedDate = d.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
console.log(formattedDate);




const newDate = new Date();
const newDateToString = newDate.toLocaleTimeString('en-us',{timeZoneName:'shortGeneric'});
const replaceString = newDateToString.replace("India Standard Time", "(IST)")
console.log(replaceString);




I need for all countries. Not only for "India Standard Time"

Maybe;


const d = new Date();
console.log(d.toLocaleTimeString('en-us',{timeZoneName:'shortGeneric'}));



